# MODULE_DESCRIPTION as runtime generated string

Tags: linux, module, kernel

Is it possible to set the MODULE_DESCRIPTION in a linux kernel module to be a runtime generated string, or does it have to be predefined, such as with #define or " "?

I'm getting this error when trying to set set it to be a runtime generated string:

```
 error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘desc’
 MODULE_DESCRIPTION(desc);
                    ^
include/linux/moduleparam.h:23:26: note: in definition of macro ‘__MODULE_INFO’
   = __stringify(tag) "=" info
                          ^
include/linux/module.h:133:42: note: in expansion of macro ‘MODULE_INFO’
 #define MODULE_DESCRIPTION(_description) MODULE_INFO(description, _description)
                                          ^
 note: in expansion of macro ‘MODULE_DESCRIPTION’
 MODULE_DESCRIPTION(desc);
 ^
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the entire macro in `moduleparam.h` you get the following:

```
#define __MODULE_INFO(tag, name, info)                                  \
static const char __UNIQUE_ID(name)[]                                   \
  __used __attribute__((section(".modinfo"), unused, aligned(1)))       \
  = __stringify(tag) "=" info
```

If you take out the `__attribute__` stuff you get something like

```
#define __MODULE_INFO(tag, name, info)                                  \
static const char __UNIQUE_ID(name)[]                                   \
  = __stringify(tag) "=" info
```

Note this line `__stringify(tag) "=" info` is creating a single string relying on the fact that the C preprocessor concatinates strings.

Therefore it cannot be a runtime generated string, it has to be something the C preprocessor can interpret and concatenate.